# Angular 2+ redirect to a url with a token

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular 9. I would like to do something similar to this, but do not want to expose the token because of security reasons.

```
<a href="https://url?jwt=xxx">
```

or

```
window.location.href = "https://url?jwt=xxx";
```

So because these two options are not a good idea, is there a way to redirect to a url and add the token to the header?  Or is there another viable way?

More info:

In my use case, I would like to redirect the user to a different url. In order to access the url, the server hosting it requires the jwt to authenticate the user.

Comment: Is adding a cookie, that can be read on the server a viable option?

Answer (score 2):

YOu should not send your JWT in the URL. Instead, you can add your token to the `windows.localstorage`. Like this

```
localStorage.setItem('token', jwt);
```

or

```
$window.localStorage.token = JSON.stringify(jwt);
```

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44209185/8826642

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44320933/8826642

Comment: Hi @theWellHoper, thanks for the answer, but this is is not what I was asking. I know I must not expose the token. I would like to redirect to another url and pass the token securely. I don't need to store the token on the browser, but rather pass it to the location I need to redirect to (i.e. the server).  So if I can set it in the header for example, that would be a viable option (but I am not sure if that is possible).

Answer (score 0):

To navigate in angular 2 and add query params

In HTML:

```
<a [routerLink]="['urlToNavTo']" [queryParams]="{jwt: tokenValue}"> link title </a>
```

Or in the TS of the component:

```
import {Router} from "@angular/router"

constructor(private router: Router) {}

this.router.navigate(['urlToNavTo'], {queryParams: {jwt: tokenValue}});
```

Hope this is what you needed.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  However, will this not expose the parameter in the url?

Comment: It is, but it's always exposed (even in the header), that's why it's  encrypted. Saving it in local storage won't help if you switch domains. Other option is to send across a session id (managed in the server)

Comment: What's your opinion on adding a cookie with the token, and then the server reads the cookie?

Comment: server reading the cookie? I could be mistaken but cookies are for the client. how would you make the server access that?

Comment: In Java you can do this: `Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();`